# Xcode : build failed due to undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: objective-c, xcode10.1

I am currently using Xcode 10.1.
I am getting the below error when am taking the build in the application.
 Can anyone tell me what was the issue from this ?
    I have been added all the frameworks and libraries. Still i am getting build error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Utils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BakerAPI.o
      objc-class-ref in ARZineViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in IssueViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The error signifies you are missing the Utils file from your project. You are trying to call it from the three files that are in the error, but the project cannot locate it. Are you sure you have added it to your project?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.
Yes i am damn sure those files have been added in the project. Can you please tell me to how to add the Utils file into my project ?

Comment: Go to ```Xcode->Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources``` and add the file manually. You might have different targets with various schemas (Debug, Release, etc).

Comment: Yes it seems everything was added into my project. I don't know why i am getting this build error ?